# Is it a good technique or a bad technique to shuffle while batting?

Tags: cricket, technique

I want to know from coaching perspective, is it good to shuffle after the ball lands on the pitch?

For right hand batsman - it's moving the right leg to reach the ball and for left hand batsman it's left leg. I was told that it's not a good technique. I have found that one could reach the pitch of the ball by shuffling keeping the head still than fishing the ball. It also depends on the reach of the batsman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "shuffling", but it's standard technique to move according to where the ball is delivered to. Keeping the head still is vital to pick up the line of the ball, then movement to get into that line and allow you play the most appropriate shot.

The standard coaching manual will suggest that the first movement should be with the back foot, and this should be across the stumps and backwards. This is used by a lot of batsmen, but by no means all. Even in international cricket there are a huge range of styles.

Comment: There is a school of thought which says, for medium pace and spinners it's a bad practise to shuffle. I honestly, didn't see the reason behind that.